# как заставить bash(find) сортировать файлы по призанку?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, скрипт, find

Имеется скрипт на актуальной версии Ubuntu server, скрипт на сортировку и копию файлов про определённым условиям, конкретное "Из папки "Б" не копировать файлы начинающиеся на "V", а в конце переносить их все с буквами маленького регистра в другую папку
Тело кода

```
 #!/bin/bash
find "/mnt/путь/." -name "*.xlsx" -or -not -name "V" | while read f;
do
fn="$(basename "$f")";
cp "${f}" "/путь/${fn,,}";
done
```

Но, это не работает так как надо

- желательно услышать пример как сделать подсчет входящих и выходящих файлов
  Заранее спасибо

Comment: вопрос не совсем поняте, о каких входящих и выходящих файлах идет речь, в вашем случае `-not -name "V"` исключает только файл с именем `V`, измените условие на `"V*"`. О какой сортировке идет речь, по какому признаку она должна проходить? Так же попробуйте использовать расширение `find` `-printf 'fn="%h"; f="%p";\n'`

Comment: Чтобы файлы типа "V" не выбирался, достаточно добавить "V*"

Comment: Осталось понять как сравнивать количество входящих файлов(Которые входят в обработку) с которыми выходят

Comment: Количество входящих и выходящих файлов будет одинаковое, можете просто в цикле добавить генератор, по типу `i=$(($i+1))`, только сам цикл переделать нужно будет, что бы за его пределами можно было вызвать результирующую переменную. `while read f; do` ... `done< <(find ...)` т.е. исключить пайп

Comment: Такой генератор может не подойти, возможно ли включить логирование? и как передать ему инф о том, что происходит в ходе операции

Comment: в заголовке написано про сортировку, в теле вопроса ни про критерии сортировки, ни про сортировку вообще нет ни слова. приведите, пожалуйста, в соотвтествие заголовок и тело вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Внимательнее прочитайте, черным по белому в конце написано

Comment: процитируйте, пожалуйста. потому как: 1. в последней фразе написано «заранее спасибо». 2. в предпоследней ничего про сортировку, только про подсчёт. 3. в пред-предпоследней тоже ничего про сортировку. 4. перед этим блок кода.

Comment: `черным по белому в конце написано` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcVMB.png, у каждого своя правда)))